# Xamarin Form: How to pass access token got from IdentityServer to WebView

Tags: session, xamarin, access-token, identityserver4

I am currently using Xamarin Form to sign in the user through the identity server 4. I was able to get the access token and use this access token to call the Web Api. Now, I want to load a a page on a web view which required authorisation. How do I use the access token to get access to the page and loaded onto a web view. 
Currently, I don't store username and password in the application only the access token.

On our website, the session was used to store the authorisation process, so the server keeps check the session of each request.

How do I get this session (Session Cookies) through the use of my access token I have saved inside my Xamarin form application?

Answer (score 0):

Using a renderer, you can get access to the underlying native WebView for each platform. Then you should be able to intercept requests and add an auth header that has the token.